is subquery allowed in if condition
correct code
"BEGIN 
    FOR ievt IN (
        SELECT 
            evt_udfchar06,evt_code,evt_enteredby 
        FROM 
            r5events 
        WHERE rowid       = :rowid ) LOOP 
        
        IF o7sess.cur_user = 'R5' AND ievt.evt_udfchar06 (SELECT evt_udfchar06 FROM r5events WHERE rowid <>:rowid) THEN 
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,''Incident number is associated with other WO.''); 
        END IF; 
        --o7sess.cur_user; 
    END LOOP; 
END;" 

PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context

is subquery allow in if condition

You're missing an equals sign. ievt.evt_udfchar06 = (SELECT evt_udfchar06 FROM r5events WHERE rowid <>:rowid)


is subquery allow in if condition

No.
Either use:

SELECT ... INTO ... before the IF statement; or

Check for other rows in the cursor:
BEGIN 
  FOR ievt IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM   (
      SELECT evt_udfchar06,
             evt_code,
             evt_enteredby,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY evt_udfchar06) AS num_rows
     FROM    r5events
   )
   WHERE  rowid = :rowid
 ) LOOP 
   IF o7sess.cur_user = 'R5'
      AND ievt.num_rows > 1
   THEN 
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'Incident number is associated with other WO.'); 
   END IF; 
   --o7sess.cur_user; 
  END LOOP; 
END;



